# Distinct records from multiple queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

Data :

```
--Table 1 :
Id ZoneName
----------- --------
20011       Name1
10027       Name1
20011       Name1
20011       Name1
20011       Name1
20074       Name1
20011       Name2
20011       Name2
10059       Name3
20011       Name2
```

Query :

```
    Select Top 2 [Id] From Table1 -- First Query
    WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
    UNION
    SELECT Top 1 [Id] from Table1 -- Second Query
    WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
    UNION
    SELECT Top 1 [Id] from Table1 -- Third Query
    WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
```

Result :

```
Id
-----
20011
```

Expected Result :

```
20011
10027
20074
```

From the above query I need 3 results from each query that do NOT overlap each other, in this case the expected result should contain the top 2 for query 1 i.e. 20011 and 10027 and for the next top 1 it should exclude those 2 results and return 20074 for query 2.

Note : I have used a single WHERE condition for this example, however in the actual query each of the query has different Where conditions, and could end up having same / different result from the query above itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH w1 AS
(
  SELECT TOP 2 [Id]
  FROM Table1 -- First Query
  WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
),
w2 AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1 [Id]
  FROM Table1 -- Second Query
  WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
  AND ID NOT IN
  ( SELECT ID
    FROM w1
  )
),
w3 AS
(
  SELECT Top 1 [Id]
  FROM Table1 -- Second Query
  WHERE ZoneName = 'Name1'
  AND ID NOT IN
  ( SELECT ID
    FROM w1
    UNION
    SELECT ID
    FROM w2
  )
)
SELECT * FROM w1
UNION
SELECT * FROM w2
UNION
SELECT * FROM w3
```